# Spyder does not recognise cython modules when importing in a script

Tags: python, import, module, cython, spyder

I have got a cython script example1.pyx with various functions. I am trying to use one of these functions in my python script. To do this I am simply trying to import the function from the cython module as follows:

```
    from example1 import myfunction1
```

I am using Spyder to run my python script. When I run it I get the following error

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example1'
```

for some reason, .pyx extension scripts are not recognised as modules that can be imported. I can successfully import other python scripts, but no luck with cython .pyx scripts. Turns out I wasnot compiling the python script. So I did so using the following script:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import numpy

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext


list_pyx = ['cydtw', 'cygak', 'cycc', 'soft_dtw_fast']
ext = [Extension(
        '%s' % s, ['%s.pyx' % s], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    ) for s in list_pyx]

setup(
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    ext_modules=ext,
    cmdclass={'build_ext': _build_ext},
)
```

when I ran this, I got the error saying I need Visual C++ 14.0 compiler. Looking at documentation in https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers, Visual Studio 15 which I have installed already should have Visual C++ 14.0 so that was confusing.  So I updated my setuptools. Got rid of that error, but turns out I it cant find a file path C;\program files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\lib. which I can see it doesn't. So that's where I am stuck now. Any clues?

Comment: You have [compiled it](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html), right?

Comment: I have just downloaded the cython script from a repository. Do i need to compile it before i can make use of it in my python script? Does python not recognise it as a module unless its compiled?

Comment: Yes - the point of Cython is that it translates the code to C which lets it run faster and access C functions directly. This means it needs to be compiled. It's likely the repository you downloaded it from has some installation instructions, and so you should follow them.

Comment: unfortunately no installation instructions available. so I looked up how to compile cython scripts and there is a nice tutorial here:

Comment: [link](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html). so I created a setup.py file and build it using setup.py build_ext, but got an error saying unable to find vcvarsall.bat. This seems related to the how python is referencing the wrong visual studio version. For background, I am using Ananconda. Windows 7 and have visual studio 15

Comment: I don't really know - I don't use Anaconda and it's been a long time since I tried to set up Cython on Windows. I know it can be a bit difficult...

Comment: To correct the _dreaded vcvarsall.bat error_ there is this link: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/CythonExtensionsOnWindows

Comment: the link mentions to check the "common tools for Visual C++" during Visual Studio install to avoid the .bat error. I already have Visual Studio 15 installed and don't remember If I checked that option. Regardless, I managed to run another setup script and got the following issues: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. This already comes with the Visual Studio 15 so that was suprising. I then went ahead and updated by setuptools library. Got around the previous error but got an error about it not recognising my path. It wants C:\\Program Files\\Mircosoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'.

Comment: I have got v8.1 but with no lib folder. Lib folder is available for v8.1a and v10.0a, but it is pointing to v8.1. Not sure what to do here

Comment: the setup file looks like this: 
 
`from setuptools import setup, Extension
import numpy

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext


list_pyx = ['cydtw', 'cygak', 'cycc', 'soft_dtw_fast']
ext = [Extension(
        '%s' % s, ['%s.pyx' % s], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    ) for s in list_pyx]

setup(
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    ext_modules=ext,
    cmdclass={'build_ext': _build_ext},
)
`

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49837155/edit) function to update your post with the relevant information. Also you might want to use @username with comments, so that people you are answering to are notified (I just saw your answer out of luck). Please include the source code you are trying to compile

Comment: @Adonis. Thanks. Just updated my post. Cant really share the code at this point, but its just a cython version of Dynamic Time Warping calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue. Didn't have the Visual C++ compiler installed on Visual Studio 2015.

To check, Open up Visual Studio 15.

Look at Templates under Visual C++.

I could see Visual C++ 2015 Tools for Windows Desktop which needed installing.

This includes tools and libraries for Windows Desktop, which includes the compiler, the Universal CRT and the windows 8.1 SDK. Ran the installation. It will ask you close visual studio in the meantime.

Was able to compile the cython scripts as well as call the functions in the script in my python project.

What I would say you have to be careful about your compiler version and python version matching up. There can be compatibility issues.

Details on Visual Studio Build Tools are available here:
https://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

For installing non-pure python packages or compile a cython or pyrex file, the details in terms of compatibility are here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: so do you still have to explicitly use that bit of compiling code within the script that you're trying to import the cython module into or is it enough to have visual studio on your system and then the import command that previously returned an error will now work?